# Python Scikit-Learn PCA: Get Component Score

Tags: python, statistics, scikit-learn

I am trying to perform a Principal Component Analysis for work. While i have successful in getting the the Principal Components laid out, i don't really know how to assign the resulting Component Score to each line item. I am looking for an output sort of like this.

```
Town       PrinComponent 1 PrinComponent 2 PrinComponent 3
Columbia     0.31989       -0.44216        -0.44369
Middletown  -0.37101       -0.24531        -0.47020
Harrisburg  -0.00974       -0.06105         0.32792
Newport     -0.38678        0.40935        -0.62996
```

The scikit-learn docs are not being helpful in this circumstance. Can anybody explain to me how i can reach this output?

The code i have so far is below.

```
def perform_PCA(df):
    threshold = 0.1
    pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=3)
    numpyMatrix = df.as_matrix().astype(float)
    scaled_data = preprocessing.scale(numpyMatrix)
    pca.fit(scaled_data)    
    pca.transform(scaled_data)

    pca_components_df = pd.DataFrame(data = pca.components_,columns = df.columns.values)
    #print pca_components_df
    #pca_components_df.to_csv('pca_components_df.csv')

    filtered = pca_components_df[abs(pca_components_df) > threshold]
    trans_filtered= filtered.T
    #print filtered.T #Tranformed Dataframe
    trans_filtered.to_csv('trans_filtered.csv')
    print pca.explained_variance_ratio_
```

Comment: The line that you have `pca.transform(scaled_data)` outputs what you're looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to add labels to that array along the lines of the template I showed in my question so that it is interpretable?

Comment: specifically is there a way to show this as a pandas dataframe with visible indexes?

Comment: Scikit-learn (currently) never outputs pandas dataframes. You can easily create one from the returned array and add your labels back in, though.

Answer (score 1):

I pumped the **transformed** array into the data portion of the DataFrame function, and then defined the index and columns the by putting them into **columns=** and **index=** respectively.

```
pd.DataFrame(data=transformed, columns=["PC1", "PC2"], index=df.index)
```